# How can you get array data in the footer of fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to get the first and last name from my array into the footer but I'm getting undefined variable error. This would work in the body of the PDF but I cant get them to work in the footer.

```
$FN = $data[0]['data']['FN2'];
$LN = $data[0]['data']['LN2'];
$Name = $FN.' '.$LN;

$this->Cell(40,8,$Name,0,0,'R');
//I also tried this but it didn't work either.I got this error-  Using $this when not in object context.
var $Name;
$FN = $data[0]['data']['FN2'];
$LN = $data[0]['data']['LN2'];
$this->Name = $FN.' '.$LN;

$this->Cell(40,8,$this->Name,0,0,'R');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the variable as a global did the trick.

```
$this->Cell(60,4,'X'.$GLOBALS["Name"],'B',0,'L');
```

Answer (score 0):

If

```
$data
```

happens to be empty, then

```
$FN
```

and

```
$LN
```

Will be undefined, causing

```
$Name
```

to be undefined (or ' ') so you can't guarantee that it is set.

Use isset to make sure that it's set, I would also check if it matches the empty string or not.

Comment: In this case I know that there is data there I can echo $Name and get the expected result but you make a good point I do need it to work if $Name is empty.